# Suppress points in exam class

Tags: exam

How do I globally suppress the display of points (for questions and for parts) in exam class?

I like to have the points display on the question sheet, but not on the answer (questions+solutions) sheet.

I tried `\nopointsinmargin` but that did not work. It only shifted the displayed points to another location.

A minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[answers]{exam}
%\documentclass{exam}
%\pointsinrightmargin
\nopointsinrightmargin
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
    \question[5]
        How long is a piece of string?
        \begin{parts}
            \part[2] Define "piece".
            \begin{solution}
                A piece is \dots
            \end{solution}
            \part[3] Define string.
            \begin{solution}
                A string is \dots
            \end{solution}
    \end{parts}
    \droppoints
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! Rather than posting code fragments it is better to give a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). Currently we have to guess what packages etc you are using and this makes it really hard to help you. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. The code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add

```
\ifprintanswers\pointformat{}\fi
```

to the preamble. The `\pointformat` macro is used to define the formatting of the printed points, by leaving it empty nothing is printed. `\ifprintanswers` means that `\pointformat{}` is only used if the `answers` option is added to the class options.

Complete code, using an example from the manual.

```
\documentclass[
% answers
]{exam}
\ifprintanswers\pointformat{}\fi
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question[7] Who was the fifth Beatle? \answerline[Murray the K]
\question[5] What is the answer to the ultimate question of life, the
universe, and everything? \answerline[42]
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Without `answers` option:

[image]

With `answers`:

[image]